# If I show a viewcontroller in iOS using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier i can not leave the view without crashing

Tags: ios, storyboard

If I show a viewcontroller in iOS using instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier, I can not leave the viewcontroller without crashing. The view loads fine and performs its tasks but when i try to leave it by pushing a button the app crashes. Is this because of some state that is wrong or have i made another mistake?

Code:

```
- (IBAction)push:(id)sender {

    UIStoryboard *mainStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:[[NSBundle mainBundle].infoDictionary objectForKey:@"UIMainStoryboardFile"] bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    NSLog(@"story: %@",mainStoryboard.description);

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    ListViewController *controller = (ListViewController*)[mainStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: @"ListId"];
    appDelegate.window.rootViewController = controller;

}
```

Comment: What is the error that you receive?

Comment: I don't get an error but the stacktrace is : http://d.pr/f/4HXu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're changing the applications root view controller as a result of pressing a button on the previous root view controller. That's not really how navigation in an iOS app should be done. Instead, try embedding your root view controller in a [UINavigationController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and then `push` and `pop` view controllers through it to navigate around your app.

If your interface doesn't fit a navigation paradigm, you could use `presentViewController:animated:completion:`.
 Regardless, you should read the [View Controller Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) as it addresses the best practices of displaying views.

Comment: thank you, embedding in navigationcontroller solved the problem